# Ionic 2 sqlite push data to other pages

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, sqlite

Hello guys I need your help,
I want to push list from provider to other pages. 
This is my sample code.

```
db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user_login")
for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
this.user_login_list = data.rows.item(i);
  return this.user_login_list.push({
    user_id: data.rows.item(i).user_id
  });                 
}
```

and on other pages how to fetch the push.

Comment: https://github.com/didinj/ionic3-angular4-cordova-sqlite-example Here are some examples on how to use sqlite.

Comment: im using provider for sqlite sir and i want to pass the result from homepage.ts

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little bit more? You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**:

You need to return `this.user_login_list` like this,

```
getAllLoginUserData() {
    return db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user_login", [])
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.user_login_list.push({ user_id: data.rows.item(i).user_id });
          }
      }
      return this.user_login_list;
    }, err => {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
      return [];
    });
}
```

Now, get data in component file,

```
this.<Your_provider_name>.getAllLoginUserData()
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can pass your data via push.
Example:

First Page:

```
constructor(
   public navCtrl: NavController,
   public navParams: NavParams
){
}

this.navCtrl.push(pageTarget, { 'DATA': data } ); //
```

Second Page:

```
constructor(
   public navCtrl: NavController,
   public navParams: NavParams
) 
{
   let data = this.navParams.get("DATA");
};
```